# How to decode tracev3 files?

Tags: macos, mac, logging

How do I decode a .tracev3 file into a human-readable format?

See [here](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/10/10/inside-the-macos-log-logd-and-the-files-that-it-manages/) for a description of why macOS creates .tracev3 files.

Thanks in advance,

James Pedersen

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268089/how-to-read-tracev3-binary-log-files and https://www.mac4n6.com/blog/2016/11/13/new-macos-sierra-1012-forensic-artifacts-introducing-unified-logging [posted as comment not answer as I've no clue how this all actually works]